# Static footer with static image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

My Objective:  To have a home page, that has a fixed, static footer.  The easiest way to explain this is looking at this website, http://www.foxtie.com/.  I'm trying to do something like what they have done with the fox, sticking with the footer, only, I'm wanting the entire footer to not ever move from the bottom of the actual screen.

My Code:  I've changed, and unchanged, and re-changed it all.  So I may be 20 steps farther than I was an hour ago.  Here is what I have.  (Bear with me, first post here, and I'm very rusty on the html/css).

Any help is appreciated.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="imginthefooter"></div>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body    {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

html {
    background-color: #999;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    position: relative;
}

#content    {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:#333;
}


#footer {
    background-color:#000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    overflow: hidden;       
}

#imginthefooter {       
    background: url(Images/Elk.png);
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    z-index:300;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: -108px;
    right: -150px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you need this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 2):

The link that Mr. Alien provided in his comment is for sticky footers. This is useful if you want the footer to appear at the bottom of the screen regardless of the amount of content on the page.  What I think that you actually want is for the footer to always appear at the bottom of the page.  Meaning that if you scroll down, the footer stays in place. If this is the case, you want the following code:

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

The fixed positioning will place the footer at the bottom of the screen permanently. To add a fixed image within the footer, you will need both a relative div and absolute div.  The following code is will get you what you want.

```
​<div id="footer">
  <div id="footerContainer">
    <div id="imginthefooter"></div>

    . . . Any additional footer elements go here . . .

  </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

#footerContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

#imginthefooter {       
    background: url(Images/Elk.png) no-repeat;
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    top: -108px;  /* Position element */
    right: 150px; /* Position element */ 
    position: absolute;
}​​​​​​​​​
```

The relative container within the fixed element will allow you to position the elk image relative to that container.

Comment: Awesome - so that takes care of 1 of my issues.  Thank you.  I now just need to know how to place an image that stays in the footer as well?

Comment: @user1041114 - I have updated my answer to include the positioning of the Elk.